# jQuery over Jquery mobile for normal web application to handle mulitple devices

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, tablet, touchscreen

**Background**

I am developing a web application, similar to trello, in which a page is seperated up into columns and tasks/cards can be added to each column, or drag and dropped between them.

This will be primarily desktop based and have a lot more functionality such as a left hand information column, and the ability to create custom layouts by adding more columns and changing styles and the likes.

Normally i would build this in HTML and CSS with JQuery for the functionality.

**Problem/Question**

Although it is primarily desktop use, we are also aware that it is likely to be used on tablet devices such as the iPad, or the surface. Also with Windows 8 out soon some desktops will start to have more touch interfaces which we would want to cater for.

My question is, would it be sensible to build this using jQuery Mobile as opposed to jQuery itself as i have heard that standard jQuery is not really set up to handle touchscreen interaction that well. On the otherhand from what i have seen of jQuery mobile it seems to be very focused on the Layout and Style which would probably be very custom for this.

Don't want to use jQuery Mobile and end up having to remove, overwrite or bodge styling and functionality to get it to work as i want, but at the same time don't want to use jQuery Standard and it not work on tablets and touch devices.

Dot worried about mobile necessarily as due to the screensize i would probably have to develop a mobile version specifically.

Thanks
Shaun

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to add touch compatibility to your webapp without all the jquery mobile visual styles, you should take a look at [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/)

Its a javascript library that supports alot of common touch events such as:

```
1. Tap 
2. Double-Tap 
3. Swipe 
4. Hold 
5. Transform 
6. Drag
```

In a browser agnostic way

Comment: But can anyone answer the question of whether it is sensible to use jQuery Mobile over standard jQuery for a web app (incase it does end up being used for more mobile devices) or would that be too limiting/restricitve?